# Find all homomorphisms

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Find all ring homomorphisms $\Phi$: $\mathbb{Z}_2 \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_6$ and
 $\Phi: \mathbb{Z}_6 \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_2$.

Comment: What are your thoughts? What have you tried so far?

Comment: I know that I have to show that for some homomorphism $\Phi: \mathbb{Z}_2 \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_6$ that $\Phi(0)_2$ maps to $\Phi(0)_6$, as well as $\Phi(1)_2$ maps to $\Phi(1)_6$.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Since both groups are generated by $1$, $\Phi$ is determined by $\Phi(1)$. What are the possible values of $\Phi(1)$ in each case?

Comment: Well in $\mathbb{Z}_2 \Phi(1) + \Phi(1) = \Phi(2) = \Phi (0)$.  But I'm just a little confused on how to go about using observations like that for finding a homomorphism from one field to another.

Comment: @Crypto Every element $x$ of $\mathbb Z_6$ (for example) is a sum of $n$ copies of $1$. So $\Phi(x)$ is a sum of $n$ copies of $\Phi(1)$. For example, if $\Phi(1)=3$ then $\Phi(4)=\Phi(1)+\Phi(1)+\Phi(1)+\Phi(1)=3+3+3+3$.